# How to debug javascript in embedded V8?

Tags: javascript, v8, embedded-v8

I'm trying to learn how to use the Debug object in V8 to debug javascript in an embedded-javascript c++ application.

I've called `v8::Debug::SetDebugEventListener` and set a callback.   I then call `v8::Debug::GetDebugContext` to get a debug context, and then run something like: `Debug.scripts()`

If I print the results of that call from C++, I get:

```
 [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
```

What I actually want to do is set a breakpoint for a given line number in a script, but can't get even the most basic things working.

I get callbacks to my debug event listener, but the callback input parameter (non-user-provided) data doesn't make any sense to me, either.

```
{script_: {context_: {data_: undefined, handle_: 0, type_: "context"}, handle_: 1, script_: {}, type_: "script"}, type_: 4}
{break_id: 2, selected_frame: 0}
```

Thank you.

Comment: One thing I didn't know when I posted this was that a bunch of information about a v8::Script is stored in v8::UnboundScript, which can be obtained from a script with `v8::Script::GetUnboundScript()`, even if you didn't explicitly make one with v8::ScriptCompiler first.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer?

Comment: @Qwertman I posetd a self-answer with what I've learned.   Debugging javascript in v8 seems to be VERY difficult and extremely poorly (even for v8) documented.

Answer (score 1):

(Note: this may or may not be the right way to do things, but it's working for me in some simple cases)

```
v8::DebugEvent debug_event_type = event_details.GetEvent();
```

then switch on the results:

```
if (debug_event_type == v8::DebugEvent::Break) {
```

Here's the passed in data for a pretty trivial breakpoint being hit:

```
 /* GetEventData() when a breakpoint is hit returns:
     * {
     *      break_points_hit_: [{active_: true, actual_location: {column: 4, line: 13, script_id: 55}, condition_: null,
     *      script_break_point_: {
     *          active_: true,
     *          break_points_: [],
     *          column_: undefined,
     *          condition_: undefined,
     *          groupId_: undefined,
     *          line_: 13,
     *          number_: 1, <== breakpoint number - v8-assigned
     *          position_alignment_: 0,
     *          script_id_: 55, <== script id passed in from v8::ScriptOrigin when compiled
     *          type_: 0
 *          },
 *          source_position_: 175}], frame_: {break_id_: 8, details_: {break_id_: 8, details_: [392424216, {}, function a(){
    println("Beginning of a()");
    let some_var = 5;
    some_var += 5;
    b(some_var);
    println("End of a()");
}, {sourceColumnStart_: [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 4, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]}, 0, 1, 175, false, false, 0, "some_var", 5]}, index_: 0, type_: "frame"}}
```

`shameless self promotion`: You can see the progress I've made towards debugging v8 in my v8 integration simplification library v8toolkit here: https://github.com/xaxxon/v8toolkit/blob/master/src/debugger.cpp